# Add routes to resources in Vapor, Swift?

Tags: swift, rest, vapor

I have a `Stall` `Resource` in a way that I have a `StallController` that inherits `ResourceRepresentable`.

I can perform `/stalls/` to get all `Stall`s, `/stalls/1` to get `Stall` of ID 1, but I want to add a route in such a way that if I do `/stalls/1/products` I can get all products under `Stall` of ID 1.

How would I add routes to a `Resource`?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Vapor doesn't currently have built-in support for nested resources right now. I'm working to get that implemented and will open a PR to the main project very soon.

Until that is done, to create a route such as `/stalls/1/products` you can do the following:

```
drop.get("stalls", ":stallID", "products") { req in
    return ...
}
```

Similarly, if you wanted to create a route like `/stalls/1/products/3/stocks`, you would write:

```
drop.get("stalls", ":stallID", "products", ":productID", "stocks") { req in
    return ...
}
```

Of course you can do this for all the supported HTTP methods.